# se requiere una referencia de objeto para el campo C#

Tags: c#, objeto, clase, static, referencias

Buen dia, regrese despues de tiempo a C# y me tope con este problemilla de referecnia en clases.

**se requiere una referencia de objeto para el campo C#** en Obj_eventlog02

```
....
using ...

namespace provando_static
{
    public partial class Formpruebaservice : Form
    {
         
        public Formpruebaservice()
        {
            InitializeComponent();            

            #region Evenlog
            Obj_eventlog02 = new EventLog();
            if (!EventLog.SourceExists("NWService"))
            {
                EventLog.CreateEventSource("NWService", "NWEventos");
            }
            Obj_eventlog02.Source = "NWService";
            Obj_eventlog02.Log = "";
            #endregion
        }

        private static void prueba_static(String[]args)
        {
            Obj_eventlog02.WriteEntry("provando static");

        }
    }
}
```

Editado...

Quiza no sea la solucion adecuada pero le quite el Static y funciono. bueno gracias de todas formas.

Comment: Obj_eventlog02.WriteEntry("provando static");.. Este objeto no existe si la clase es estatica.. cuando lo creaste?

Comment: la instancie dentro de Formpruebaservice(), alguna sugerencia para corregirla porfavor

Comment: no.. ahi instanciaste la clase, pero tu metodo es estatico, con lo cual no es de una instancia, es de todas... y solo lo instanciaste para no se que, porque no dice como esta definido... No entiendo que tratas de hacer, no se como responderte, esta mezclado lo estatico con una clase parcial.. seguro querias que fuera estatico eso?

Comment: deseo ejecutar esto Obj_eventlog02.WriteEntry("provando static"); dentro de prueba_static sabiendo es static , no se me ocurre como.

Comment: Pero si es static, el objeto deberia ser creado a nivel de clase estatica no?

Comment: Es muy raro que tengas un metodo estatico dentro de un form..

Comment: Me ha funcionado siempre solo a qué hasta ahora al susodicho se le ocurrió que ya no se usa así. Alguna propuesta para ordenarlo ? Podría gravarlo como variable global y acceder a gusto pero ya estoy algo oxidado

Comment: no creo que sea que se le ocurrio que ahora no funcionaba asi.. probablemente te este faltando algo mas..

Comment: no puedo proponerte nada, porque no entiendo que tratas de hacer con ese metodo estatico...

Comment: Realmente no pensé que sería necesario enviarte todo el código para que sea legible si a la final es lo mismo, pero ahí va.

Comment: si ariel ayer estaba muy sacado de contexto, en fin supongo que a todo mundo le sucede o sera que al buen señor ariel no se le ha ido una algun momento, me quito el sompbrero si asi es... en fin lo resolvi y gracias por criticar en vez de ayudar.